# Is a FTP Client supported for Tumblr?

Tags: ftp, tumblr

Since a couple of days, I'm having a Tumblr blog. Can I use a FTP Client like Transmit or FileZilla to upload my HTML files etc.?

And *if* that is possible, can you tell me where I find those FTP login stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, tumblr requires you to upload any html code via their own system for updating your blog. You can however host things elsewhere, then refer/call them from your tumblr code.

People have tried small 'campaigns' before, to get tumblr to offer FTP but there hasn't been any visible success from these.